# UWP Initialize components not recognised after clean System.Xaml could not be found

Tags: uwp, build-error, initializecomponent

So I got a problem with my UWP project after I **cleaned** my project... The `InitializeComponent()` method was no longer recognized and found by Visual Studio, so I was not able to build and so on... 
I've been searching the whole day and did'nt find anything helpfull... Also the error message was a charm...
So these where the steps I made before I got the error:

- Wrote some XAML in the XAML-Designer
- Accidentally cleaned the solution instead of building it
- Then built it

→ The project could not be built because **System.Xaml** was missing and if I missed an assembly reference... but I never used System.Xaml never and did nether change the references in code file nor did I change the project references

The question was **"How to solve this problem?"**

So after searching and analyzing the project I noticed that **there was a reference** to a project in my project references which I've never seen before... It was something like **Presentation**...

So the solution was to remove this reference and build the project then it worked so if you get this error the only reference you need for it is **UniversalWindows** and maybe the `Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` NuGet package.

So remove all and just leave those... If the error disappears add the missing references again... 
Hopefully this works for you too.

Comment: The answer is already included and posted below so it is solved but i can't mark it as solved because I have to wait 2 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution was to remove this reference and build the project then it worked so if you get this error the only reference you need for it is **UniversalWindows** and maybe the **Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform NuGet** package.

So remove all and just leave those... If the error disappears add the missing references again... 
Hopefully this works for you too.